# Deleting Large Number of Data From Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle

Which is the best way to delete large records from a table ? I have requirement in which I need to delete some 30 Million records from a table on a weekly basis.
Problem here is that, there is an UNDO retention issue. I am planning to break my delete statements in to chunks so that it will help.

Current Statement

```
DELETE FROM LARGE_TABLE WHERE LARGE_ID ='someValue';
```

Details of Table :

1.Table will have around 70 Million records.

2.Delete will affect at least 40-45% table.

3.Table is not partitioned.

Planning to change the statement to

```
LOOP 

DELETE FROM LARGE_TABLE WHERE LARGE_ID ='someValue' and ROWNUM <'some row number';
COMMIT;
select count(1) INTO nCountValue from LARGE_TABLE WHERELARGE_ID ='someValue' ;
EXIT WHEN nCountValue = 0;

END LOOP;
```

Main idea is that this will reduce the UNDO retention.

Question, Is it the best practice to do ? If not, any pointers ? Please help

Comment: "*UNDO retention*" is a system parameter to specify (loosely speaking) how large the UNDO tablespace can grow. It is definitely not affected by any transaction. You probably expect this to reduce the size of the UNDO *tablespace*.

Comment: My understanding is that, when delete statement is fired, until there is a commit, the deleted data will be in UNDO retention. Am I correct? If so then it is causing issue here, since the data is very huge.

Comment: Do you have a problem? An error? or the delete statement is just slow?

Comment: No. The data will be in the UNDO **tablespace**. UNDO *retention* is a system parameter specifying an amount of time (so it's a *single value*)

Comment: @Florin,

DBAs are getting following alarm "Snapshot Too Old due to Tablespace Limit "

Comment: Snapshot too old while deleting... I think your table is changing while the statement runs and the statement runs enough time that the engine is unable to keep track of the changed blocks because the rollback information is overwritten.

Comment: You should open the cursor after every commit. This is also the reason not to want to commit for every row but for a batch of rows. Using batches will reduce the commit overhead and also the undo space.

Comment: @ik_zelf There is no cursor in the code(There is one in PGA :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, I will

```
CREATE TABLE LARGE_TABLE_NEW AS
SELECT * FROM LARGE_TABLE 
WHERE LARGE_ID <> 'someValue';

rename LARGE_TABLE to LARGE_TABLE_old;

Rename LARGE_TABLE_new to LARGE_TABLE;
```

Verify anything is ok and then;

```
drop table LARGE_TABLE_OLD;
```

recreate indexes, constraints (better you save them before drop);

This will be faster because insert is faster than delete. More faster.

Comment: Nice approach, you find any drawbacks with mine ?

Comment: do you have an index on large_id?

Comment: Yes, there is a an index on large_id

Comment: The index will slow the delete from table. But will help your aproach, because finding rows is very fast. However I find my aproach better as far you don't have online requirements.

Comment: Thanks Florin, The only thing which is stopping me to use your approach is, the delete Query is Dynamic one, I have utility package to which I feed table name and where clause which will take care of deletion. recreating index in this scenario is difficult, Anyway thanks for the approach.

Comment: It's worth to do a test. Test both and see what matches better your requirements and possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

TO DROP TABLE PERMANENTLY, IF YOUR DATA BASE IS 10G use purge

drop table LARGE_TABLE_OLD purge;

Because, from 10g dropped table can be replaced, so therefore to [delete it permanently](http://newtonapples.com/oracle-sql-drop-table/), you need to use purge.

Comment: Thanks Bharath, am on 11g and i wont be using drop.